# creating a game in matlab and port it to android.

Tags: android, matlab

I'm new at this and i took a liking into try and create a game.

So, I know the best way to create a game to android would be in JAVA.

The thing is, I'm way much more confortable programming in matlab, so as the title says, what i want to ask is :

Is there a way/tutorial to create a game in matlab and port it to android?

many Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662730/how-to-integrate-matlab-code-library-with-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do that. I also am much more confortable programming in Matlab. However, I suggest that you try other language.

I started to learn Python 2.7 a few months ago. You will quickly feel confortable in this language and it offers more advantages if you want to create a cool game.

Python has some modules (numpy and scipy) that have a lot of the functionalities that you are used to in Matlab.

There are a lot of online courses to learn Python also.

You can also try to learn Android or Java, but I think that's a higher jump to take.
Good luck!