# Can we implement MATLAB code on Android?

Tags: android, matlab, matlab-coder

I basically am using MATLAB for image processing. I want to develop an Android app which can support the processing provided by MATLAB. I searched for results about it but failed to get clarity out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an additional product, [MATLAB Builder JA for Java](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/), you can produce a .jar file from your MATLAB code.

> However, the .jar file requires the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (a freely
>   redistributable component that you get with MATLAB Compiler and MATLAB
>   Builder products) to be present. The MCR has a much larger footprint
>   than is suitable for the typical Android device (it's like a copy of
>   MATLAB itself, without the user interface).

You could think about either

Running your MATLAB .jar file remotely on a server, and having your Android application connect to it, or

> Instead of using MATLAB Compiler and Builder products, use MATLAB
>   Coder, which will convert a subset of the MATLAB language directly
>   into C code. This C code doesn't require the MCR, and could be
>   compiled to run directly on Android. Make sure your MATLAB algorithm
>   falls within, or can be expressed in, the appropriate subset of the
>   MATLAB language.

More infos can be found [here from Sam Roberts post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662730/how-to-integrate-matlab-code-library-with-android)

Comment: Rather than copy/pasting my answer to another question, it would be more useful to point the questioner to it, and mark the question as duplicate.