# making code in MATLAB and connected with Android Studio

Tags: android, matlab

I want to create mobile apps in Android Studio with source code form MATLAB. I absolutely finish code in MATLAB. Now I want an application that has been created in MATLAB, can be used in Android Studio. What should I do for it?

Comment: Sorry, we would need a more specifications about what you want to be able to answer this question, though I fear there are no simple answer. First, do you want to run Matlab from android or do you want to create a standalone android app? You can also take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662730/how-to-integrate-matlab-code-library-with-android).

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the Mathworks MATLAB Mobile expansion. I don't see any other "easy" way to achieve what you request.

http://ch.mathworks.com/mobile/